# Boxed Text Styling - Python 3.x - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been looking online for a good few hours on how to achive this 
[image]

I remember seeing this somewhere, i'm not sure where if anyone could link it to me or reply with some code that would reproduce this that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming are referring to the border with the word "Title" in it, that is called a [LabelFrame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm). Both the tkinter and ttk packages define a `LabelFrame` class.

Example:

```
# python 2
# import Tkinter as tk
# import ttk

# python 3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()

lf1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Title (tkinter)", width=400, height=100)
lf2 = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Title (ttk)", width=400, height=100)
lf1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=4, pady=4)
lf2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly